# Page transitions with css3 content overflowing

Tags: html, css, transition

I am trying to implement page transitions with CSS3. I have achieved this but for some strange reason the content from the [home](http://engineer.org.in/events/chem-events/the_portal.php#home) panel is appearing on every other panel also. Its overflowing. How can i fix this?
Here is the [link](http://engineer.org.in/events/chem-events/the_portal.php#home)

(ex - when you click on [rounds](http://engineer.org.in/events/chem-events/the_portal.php#rounds) you can see the content from home on rounds panel also)

Comment: You never hide the "home" `panel`

Comment: my "home" is not a "panel", how do i hide it?